# Fastest way to write to database from script

Tags: spotfire

SQL server write script:

```
sqlCommand = "INSERT INTO ...

ds = DatabaseDataSource(DatabaseDataSourceSettings("System.Data.SqlClient","Server=xxx;Database=xxx;UID=xxx;PWD=xxx",sqlCommand))

#execute by creating a temp table with db source, then drop table
newDataTable = Document.Data.Tables.Add("temp",ds)
Document.Data.Tables.Remove(newDataTable)
```

However there is a slight delay in this method. Is it possible to do this without creating a temp table?

Comment: Have you consider using parameterized information links by modifying the original sql and prepending insert statements?

Comment: Briefly have you got an example? Do you think this will be quicker?

Comment: You can use information links to write back to the database if that is what you are trying to do. Just create your update statement using the SQL button under the Pre-Updates or Post-Updates. Make sure you return something back to Spotfie using the Query option. The radio buttons are misleading. They should be tabs because you might think that it will execute one or the ohter, but not all. example: update dev.myTable set status=?status, comment_text=?comment, USERNAME='%CURRENT_USER%' where itemId in (?selectedIds) and set your parameters (if any) under the parameters section

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thought I'd answer my own question from ages ago. It's possible to avoid the Spotfire libraries and use .NET System.Data.SqlClient for a much faster execution with this simple script:

```
import clr, datetime
clr.AddReference('System.Data')
from System.Data import SqlClient
from System import Threading, DateTime

sql = "INSERT INTO ...."

conn = SqlClient.SqlConnection("Server=;Database=;UID=;PWD=")
conn.Open()

cmd = SqlClient.SqlCommand(sql, conn)
exe = cmd.ExecuteReader()

exe.Close()
conn.Close()
```

Comment: That's amazing! Thanks for sharing